# RandomAccessFile causing program to "hang" and freeze Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, io, freeze

I have a few methods which are reading and writing out to a file in my program however when I call upon them they are freezing my program, making the whole frame unresponsive.

Here are my Methods:

```
public static int read() throws IOException
{
    int x = 0;
    boolean eof = false;
    File in = new File("file.dat");

    RandomAccessFile rd = new RandomAccessFile(in, "rw");

    try
    {
        do
        {

            x = rd.readInt();
        } while (!eof);
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        rd.close();
    }

    return x;
}


public static void first() throws IOException 
{



    try
    {
        File out = new File("file.dat");


        RandomAccessFile rd = new RandomAccessFile(out, "rw");

        if (out.exists())
        {
            rd.seek(0);
        }



            rd.writeInt(10000000);

            rd.close();
    }



    catch (IOException ex)
    {

    }


}


public static int checkBest() throws IOException
{
    int new= 0, old; 
    boolean eof = false;
    File in = new File("file.dat");

    RandomAccessFile rd = new RandomAccessFile(in, "rw");

    try
    {
        do
        {

            old= rd.readInt();

            System.out.print("" + old);
            if (old > myTime) // myTime is a timer variable 
            {
                new = myTime;


            }
            else 
                new = old;

        } while (!eof);
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {

        rd.close();
    }
    System.out.print(new);
    return new;
    }


public static void addBest(int x) throws IOException
{
    boolean eof = false;
    File in = new File("file.dat");

    RandomAccessFile rd = new RandomAccessFile(in, "rw");

    try
    {
        do
        {


            rd.writeInt(x);




        } while (!eof);
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {

        rd.close();
    }

}
```

Im using the check best in the addBest method, so it appears as addBest(checkBest); Its causing the window to become unresponsive when I use a menu option calling read() or addBest.

I feel like I have missed something obvious but I can't seem to find any information online so any help is very appreciated.

Comment: You must be reading and writing *with-in* the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Don't do that.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: `catch (IOException ex)
    {

    }` It's a poor practice to ignore exceptions. In lieu of logging, change it to: `catch (IOException ex)
    {
ex.printStackTrace(); /* report the exception & provide details */
    }`

Comment: use swingworker for those kind of purposes.

Comment: thanks all for the responses, @AndrewThompson I've read through the article you linked but I can't locate the fix in it? Could you point me towards it?

Comment: *" point me towards it?"* `SwingWorker` as mentioned by @kaanyılmaz ..